# What does float long and float short mean with respect to ferrite core transformer windings?

Tags: transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, ferrite, winding, secondary-winding

I have winding instructions for winding a EE13-06 ferrite core transformer, for secondary it's written 0.23 mm TIW,

no. of wire = 1,

no. of turns = 66,

start = float short,

finish = float long.

What does float long and float short mean? What is their utility?

Comment: Does it have a bobbin with pins or flying leads?

Comment: It sounds like you leave a flying lead, rather than terminate it to a pin on a bobbin, but that's a guess as I've not heard the term before. Leaving them long and short will help distinguish the start and finish. Unimportant for a single winding, but if you have several windings you will probably need them to have the right polarity with respect to each other.

Comment: Please provide a link to the original document.

Answer (score 1):

Tried to explain with my horrible drawing skills:

[image]

Red here is the floating short (start) and blue is the floating long (finish), and arrows represent the winding directions of each layer.

0.23mm TIW has probably a final diameter of 0.38-0.4mm. Assuming you have a standard EE13 bobbin with a window breadth of 8.7mm, one layer of winding will take 8.7/0.4=22 turns. So you'll probably wind 3 layers. This means that you'll start at one end and finish at the other end *(Even if one layer takes slightly higher than 22 turns you'll finish winding at quite close to the other end of the window)*. That's why the floating (or flying) wires will be short at start and long at finish.